# eclipse (Saving workbench state)

Tags: eclipse, process

I have a problem with Eclipse. 
Sometimes when I try to close **'Eclipse'**, the progress bar stops and  doesn't move..
**Saving workbench state.**

The only way to end a proccess it's kill it.
Print screen attached.
[image]

Comment: Maybe someone has the same problem with 'eclipse'. I don't know what to think. Is it bug or not..

Comment: which version are you using? try to create a new workspace (change location or remove the existing one) or update your eclipse.

Comment: I have Eclipse IDE for Java Developers

Version: Indigo Service Release 2
Build id: 20120216-1857
(c) Copyright Eclipse contributors and others 2000, 2012.  All rights reserved.

Comment: @Dezigo: I use both Eclipse Juno and Indigo. My Indigo is exact the same version with yours, and no problems with it, so I do not consider the problem you've got is a bug.

Comment: May be Java run out of memory. Check your settings in `eclipse.ini` (`-Xmx` option)

Comment: @maverik I'm already done it, eclipse running faster but the same result

Comment: This looks like the bug in question: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=392794 . Unfortunately no fix or workaround other than kill the process.

Comment: To update this a bit, still no fix it seems.  I just checked the link rdc provided above and there are developer comments as recently as two days ago.

Comment: This issue will be fixed in 4.4.2: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=392794

Comment: @Dan: Not true - still happening in Mars a year and a half later.

Comment: Still happen with a fresh empty workspace ? If the workspace is corrupt time to time it's happen, create a new empty workspace and import project into the new one could solve the problem.

Comment: @AmosM.Carpenter: And happening in Neon too.

Comment: Those are at least two questions here: 1.) How to prevent this. 2.) How to recover if it happens.

Answer (score 2):

I meet the same probelm , I had to  kill the proccess of eclipse and restart it , it worke again.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue and solved it as follows (on Linux):

1. Kill and restart Eclipse
2. Identify which project causes this issue by right-clicking each open project and select "Close Project" (the one that doesn't close is causing this behaviour)
3. Right-click the project and select "Delete" (be sure
   **not** to check the option to remove the files!)
4. Close (and kill if needed) Eclipse
5. Open the folder where the project you identified is located at and remove the (hidden) folder ".settings" and the files ".buildpath" and ".project"
6. Start Eclipse and add the project

Answer (score 0):

I was also having this problem.  I went and closed several projects in my workspace and now it exits quickly.